# Failing to build Liferay: build-ext

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, content-management-system, liferay

I am trying to build liferay and I have following this tutorial: 
http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Development%20Environment%20%28Windows%29

In the step where I have to build the sources, I get a fail with this message:

> Target 
>   "build-ext" does not exist in the project "protal"

The version of Liferay I am using is 6.0.5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the tutorial you are referring too is for liferay version 4-5

from 6, the ext env. no longer exist, it's was replaced by the plugin sdk